# How can I embed a slide from a presentation package in LyX?

Tags: lyx

I'm writing a document and I'd like to include a slide from a presentation in .PDF format verbatim. How can I do that? Do I want to mess with ImageMagick or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't. ImageMagick does generally a terrible job of converting regular PDF files with text in vector formats like SVG; trying with the slide I wanted to import got me a 18 MB monster that took minutes to rasterize as every single character got converted into a curve; a lot of color information was also lost in the process. LaTeX, otoh, has quality inbuilt support for embedding PDFs.

Insert a graphic as usual (perhaps in its own float: *Insert → Floating → Figure*; *Insert → Figure*), then select the PDF file as your source, tweak the size to your needs (for example, set the width to 80% of text width) then switch to the "settings" tab. Here, you can specify which slide you want included. If you want page 24 of the PDF, write in:

```
page=24
```

in the LaTeX settings box. (Yes, the page numbering starts from 1.) Also disable the LyX preview, as LyX won't handle this setting and will instead show you page 1 for its preview.

Done!